# NESTJS How can I access the server instance from a WebSocketGateway in another service within the same module in NestJS?

Tags: nestjs

How can I access the server instance from a WebSocketGateway in another service within the same module in NestJS? I have tried injecting the WebSocketAdapter provided by the platform-socket.io package, but it doesn't seem to work. I keep getting the error "Nest can't resolve dependencies of the [ServiceName] (?). Please make sure that the argument dependency at index [0] is available in the [Module] context."

My service is in the same module as the gateway, and I need to access `@WebSocketServer() server: Server` from the service. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I want to clarify that I am using socket.io.

```
    @WebSocketGateway({ cors: true })
    export class PaymentGateway {
      constructor(private readonly paymentService: PaymentService) {}

      @WebSocketServer() server: Server

      @SubscribeMessage('pay')
      @UsePipes(new WSValidationPipe())
      create(@MessageBody() createPaymentDto: CreatePaymentDto,
             @ConnectedSocket() client: Socket
      ) {
        return this.paymentService.create(createPaymentDto, client)
      }
    }
```

```
@Injectable()
    export class PaymentService {
      constructor(private botService: BotService) {}

      async create(createPaymentDto: CreatePaymentDto, client: Socket) {
        // ...
      }

      async sendError(error: ILogError, socketId: string) {
        // this.server.emit('error', error.text) <--- how???
      }
    }
```

I was unable to access `@WebSocketServer() server: Server.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I wouldn't. I would use an RxJS subject in the service for values that should be emitted by the socket and subscribe to that subject as an observable inside the gateway. [A repo with an example can be found here](https://github.com/jmcdo29/nest-samples/tree/main/apps/socket-subject)

The idea is to do something like

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  private events$ = new Subject<{ name: string; data: unknown }>();

  getData(): { message: string } {
    this.addEvent('message', 'GET / hit');
    return { message: 'Welcome to socket-subject!' };
  }

  addEvent(name: string, data: unknown) {
    this.events$.next({ name, data });
  }

  getEventsToEmit() {
    return this.events$;
  }
}
```

With a gateway like

```js
import { OnGatewayInit, WebSocketGateway } from '@nestjs/websockets';
import * as ws from 'ws';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@WebSocketGateway()
export class AppGateway implements OnGatewayInit {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  afterInit(server: ws.WebSocketServer) {
    this.appService
      .getEventsToEmit()
      .asObservable()
      .subscribe({
        next: (event) => {
          server.emit(event.name, event.data);
        },
      });
  }
}
```

Now in other services you can inject the `AppService` (or whatever you have it called) and use the `addEvent()` method to dynamically add events for the server to emit back to the client.

Comment: Using your example, I tried to send a message, but it didn't work. I also tried to add a console.log() in the next() function, but it didn't output anything.

Comment: Were you listening for whatever event was being emitted on the front end?

Comment: I am testing socket.io using an extension, so I can see everything that is sent and received.

Comment: I've tested the code above, I'm certain it works with both ws and socket.io.

Comment: I tested the code and found out that it works only with the controller. But when I call the sendError() function from another place, it doesn't work. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: @WWCode I'm going to assume that you have`AppService` in multiple `providers` arrays which would end up creating multiple `Subject`s and so the Subject your gateway is subscribing to may not be the subject you are pushing on to. Without seeing your code, it'll be hard to know for certain

Comment: Your `AppModule`, `BotModule`, and `PaymentModule` **all** add `PaymentService` to the `providers` arrays, so you have three instances of that provider. Rather, your `PaymentsService` should have it in the `providers` and `exports` and your `BotModule` and `AppModule` should **only** have the `PaymentsModule` in the `imports` and not reference the `PaymentsService` at all. This will ensure only one instance is created